# FindMany overwritten doesn't work. Ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

In my project, if I ask my server for the records with id 1,2,3 like this (without spaces):

```
url?sites=id1 %2C id2 %2C id3
```

It will return a json file with the records for this ids.

So for this case I think I can have then cached if I manage to use findMany and make the RestAdapter make the call to the server in this way.

I have found the next, but it doesnt work, it continues calling:

```
GET topologymins/1,2
```

Adapter:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

  findMany: function(store, type, ids) {
    Ember.Logger.log("INSIDE THE findMany"); // NOT SHOWED
    var url = type.url;
    url = url.fmt(ids.join(','));

    jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        // data is an Array of Hashes in the same order as the original
        // Array of IDs. If your server returns a root, simply do something
        // like:
        // store.loadMany(type, ids, data.people)
        //store.loadMany(type, ids, data);
    });
}
});

App.Topologymin.reopenClass({
    url: '/something?ids=%@'
});
```

My call:

```
this.store.find('topologymin',[1, 2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just because you're missing a return?

Oh... sorry your findMany isn't written correctly, I don't htink... it's missing a return... but that isn't actually what's wrong - it's not even calling the findMany because store.find() can't be passed an array of ids... you want this, I think: store.find('topologymin', { ids: [1,2] });

However, I think you'll have another problem in that findMany should have a return value in it... if you look at the default implementation, you'll see what I mean... it needs to return a promise, and you're not returning anything.

Comment: Where? I dont think so

Comment: Oh... sorry your findMany isn't written correctly, I don't htink... it's missing a return... but that isn't actually what's wrong - it's not even calling the findMany because store.find() can't be passed an array of ids... you want this, I think: store.find('topologymin', { ids: [1,2] });

Comment: That would call the findQuery function, which never cashes the records. Anyway, I think right now it cant be done

Comment: findQuery doesn't seems to specify anything to do with caching... why wouldn't it cache? fair enough I don't purport to understand all of this stuff to a high degree...

Comment: Because it doesnt understand that a query will return always the same records, so it doesnt cash them.